# I would like to make a program with which you can write other programs

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, exec, nested-function

I am having a problem `exec`ing the combined strings for the code, it returns the error:  unqualified exec in function 'python' it is a nested function

Also sometimes, it does not return an error, but instead results in no output whatsoever.

```
def python():
        prompt=">>> "
        lines=0
        fullcode=""
        enter="\n"
        print "\nPython 2.7.8"
        print "\nEnter your lines of code, when you are finished enter 'end'."
        for x in range(1,1000):
            code=raw_input(prompt)
            if "end" not in code.lower():
                globals()['line%s' % x] = code
                lines+=1
            else:
                break
        for x in range(1,lines):
            y=x+1
            fullcode+=globals() ['line%s' %x] + enter
        try:
            exec fullcode
        except:
            print "Error"
python()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you directly manipulating the `globals()` dict like that?

Anyway, you need to provide `exec` a context to work in. The full form is

`exec fullcode in globals(), locals()`

but in your code you shouldn't specify `locals()` unless you want to give the user access to the local variables defined in your `python` function.

Also, your conversion loop ends too early, it should be

`for x in range(1, lines + 1):`

Here's an edited version of your code that should do what you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def python():
        prompt=">>> "
        lines=0
        fullcode=""
        enter="\n"
        print "\nPython 2.7.8"
        print "\nEnter your lines of code, when you are finished enter 'end'."
        for x in range(1,1000):
            code=raw_input(prompt)
            if "end" not in code.lower():
                globals()['line%s' % x] = code
                lines+=1
            else:
                break
        for x in range(1,lines+1):
            fullcode+=globals()['line%s' %x] + enter
        try:
            exec fullcode in globals() #, locals()
        except Exception, e:
            print "Error:", e

python()
```

And here's an alternate version of your code that doesn't store each line as a new variable in `globals()`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import readline

def python():
        prompt = ">>> "
        codelines = []
        print "\nPython 2.7.8"
        print "\nEnter your lines of code, when you are finished enter 'end'."
        while True:
            code = raw_input(prompt)
            if "end" not in code.lower():
                codelines.append(code)
            else:
                break

        fullcode = '\n'.join(codelines)
        #print `fullcode`
        try:
            exec fullcode #in globals(), locals()
        except Exception, e:
            print "Error:", e

python()
```

The `import readline` statement gives you line editing; but IIRC it doesn't work in Windows.